# Can you run Montreal Forced Aligner for bilingual data?

Tags: phoneme

I have audio files from a bilingual speaker (who speaks German and Turkish). I am trying to get the phoneme level annotation for the same using MFA. Is there anyway I can get accurate outputs?

I am getting a messed up output.

Comment: This is too vague in its current form. Please try to find more specific tags that identify the language and the packages you use. It is fine to mention in the question body that Anaconda and Miniconda are used to manage software, but you do not need help from an Anaconda or Miniconda expert (which is what those tags signal).